# How does electron listen to the global 'CmdOrCtrl+C' event without affecting the system's native copy event?

Tags: javascript, electron

Im using the electron and I want to use globalShortcut.register to achieve the effect of the deepl shortcut key (continuous click on ctrl+c to open the translation software). However, after listening to CmdOrCtrl+C, the system's built-in copy function will not be triggered.

Can someone help me solve this problem? Thank you very much.

```
globalShortcut.register('CmdOrCtrl+C', () => {
   ...
})
```